# Column Validation Preventing Me From Copying/Updating List Items (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, csom, list-item, date

There is a date list column I'm having trouble updating since there is a validation formula linked to it.

```
=(TEXT([Week Ending],"dddd")="Saturday")
```

The date that gets inputted for the `Week Ending` column must be on a Saturday.  What I'm trying to do is copy some items from that same list based on a query, and certain columns (not all) will be updated with new values. The query works fine (returning the expected number of items) and I have the new date value in a format that SharePoint list accepts (MM/dd/yyyy) if I was using the SharePoint UI to update/add it.  The thing is in PowerShell, it throws a "List data validation error" even though it's in the same date format used to add an item to the list manually.  I really think the error has something to do with the validation formula above.  Since it's using `dddd` and not `dd` like in the format used by the PowerShell.

And the date I'm using to update items does fall on a Saturday, so it makes me think it's how I'm formatting it primarily.

Basically, an item won't get updated with a new date because the validation formula is causing some issues even though it's in the seemingly correct format and passes the validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it ended up being a very simple solution to this.  The date I was using to update the items was a string, and I needed to convert it to a date object.  There didn't need to be any changes made to the validation formula or date formatting aside from converting "MM/dd/yyy" by using this (`$newItemDate` was the original date string):

```
$newItemDate = [datetime]$newItemDate
```